# how to completely remove cuda toolkit/driver from ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall

I am on a Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I have installed Cuda driver and toolkit, and now I want to remove them.

I have installed manually so they does not appear in synaptic/apt.

I have removed the driver from "Additional Driver". Well, they are inactive but still in the list. How to completely remove them?

Then, I have the toolkit in `/usr/local/cuda`, how to remove it completely and safely? I don't think that `rm -r /usr/local/cuda` is the right way..

some advice

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: `sudo sh cuda_5.0.35_linux_64_ubuntu11.10.run `, following this post: http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda5.0-ubuntu .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just ran the installer and at the end it says

```
To uninstall CUDA, remove the CUDA files in /usr/local/cuda-5.0
```

So you should be fine simply removing it.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda (my formatting):

"If you want to totally remove Cuda, juste delete the `/opt/cuda` and `~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK` folders:

```
rm -r ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK
sudo rm -r /opt/cuda
```

and remove the `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib:/opt/cuda/lib64` lines of the `~/.bash_profile` file.